# How to write a unicode character to a file that is not supported by utf-8, python

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, file-io, utf-8

I'm trying to write some Hebrew text to a .txt file using python, but seeing as Hebrew is non-Ascii and non utf-8 I am getting errors. I am trying to have get literal text שלום in the text file as opposed to a representation of it.

```
hebrew_word = "שלום"

file = open("file_with_hebrew.txt", "w")
file.writelines(hebrew_word)
file.close()
```

part of my stack trace:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u05e9' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: "Hebrew is non-UTF-8"? Err, nope. It's perfectly fine UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hebrew_word = "שלום"

with open('file_with_hebrew.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    #                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    file.writelines(hebrew_word)
```

Make sure you specify an encoding when opening the file; in your case it defaulted to an encoding not able to represent Hebrew.

Answer (score 1):

Your script work just fine. You are doing right and UTF-8 is OK to print those characters. What Python version are you using on what platform?

From [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) doc:

> In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is
>   platform dependent: locale.getpreferredencoding(False) is called to
>   get the current locale encoding.

So you should specify the encoding when open the file to write in case that your platform doesn't have UTF-8 as default:

```
hebrew_word = "שלום"

with open("file_with_hebrew.txt", "w", encoding='UTF-8') as file
    file.writelines(hebrew_word)
```

Comment: I am using python 3.5.1 @deceze answer works by declaring the encoding at the beginning

Comment: Correct. Take a look at the doc I linked in my answer, is very well explained there. BTW, on what OS you are running that script?

Comment: I'm using windows